# Expand each row in a dataframe using a vector of values to fill it

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am working with a dataframe in `R`. I need to expand my dataframe `df1`:

```
#Code
df1 <- data.frame(v=paste0('P',1:3))
```

So that each row is "expanded" with a vector `val`:

```
#Code vector
val <- c("cherry", "apple", "kiwi")
```

In the end I would like to get this output:

```
df2
   v    val
1 P1 cherry
2 P1  apple
3 P1   kiwi
4 P2 cherry
5 P2  apple
6 P2   kiwi
7 P3 cherry
8 P3  apple
9 P3   kiwi
```

Many thanks. If possible a `dplyr` or `tidyr` solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way is using `nest` from `tidyr` package:
Note it ends with the same order as desired:

```
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(v = paste0('P', 1:3))
val <- c("cherry", "apple", "kiwi")

df1 %>% 
  mutate(val = list(val)) %>% 
  unnest(val)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  v     val   
  <chr> <chr> 
1 P1    cherry
2 P1    apple 
3 P1    kiwi  
4 P2    cherry
5 P2    apple 
6 P2    kiwi  
7 P3    cherry
8 P3    apple 
9 P3    kiwi
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `expand.grid` from `base R`

```
expand.grid(c(list(val = val), df1))[2:1]
  v    val
1 P1 cherry
2 P1  apple
3 P1   kiwi
4 P2 cherry
5 P2  apple
6 P2   kiwi
7 P3 cherry
8 P3  apple
9 P3   kiwi
```

---

Or with `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(df1, val)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  v     val   
  <chr> <chr> 
1 P1    apple 
2 P1    cherry
3 P1    kiwi  
4 P2    apple 
5 P2    cherry
6 P2    kiwi  
7 P3    apple 
8 P3    cherry
9 P3    kiwi
```